# Templated deriving from a template

Tags: c++, templates

Given two templated classes which are very similar but behave differently:

```cpp
template<class T>
firstBase {};

template<class T>
secondBase {};
```

Now I've got this other class, which, based on it's template parameter, will derive either from `firstBase` or from `secondBase`:

```cpp
template<class B, class T>
myClass : public B<T> { /* T is used in here */ };
```

Well, that does not work. The compiler tells me that `B` is an unknown template name. (`error: unknown template name 'B'`)

My current workaround is to define `myClass` as

```cpp
template<class B, class T>
myClass : public B { /* T is used in here */ };
```

and the caller of `myClass` needs to intatiate it via `myClass<b<t>, t>` instead of `myClass<b, t>`.

The latter would be really nice and reduce some copy&paste code. Is there any other way of achieving this?

---

*In my use case I'm trying to implement a `deep_const_ptr` for the pimpl idiom enabling 'true constness'. Depending on whether `myClass` needs to be copy-assignable or not, it either uses `deep_const_ptr<std::shared_ptr>` or `deep_const_ptr<std::unique_ptr>` for its private pointer.*

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class pointerT, class typeT>
class deep_const_ptr : public pointerT
{
  public:
    explicit deep_const_ptr(typeT* ptr) : pointerT(ptr) { }

    // overloading pointerT::operator->() for non-constant access
    typeT* operator->() {
      std::cout << "deep_const_ptr::operator->()" << std::endl;
      return pointerT::operator->();
    }

    // overloading pointerT::operator->() for constant access
    const typeT* operator->() const {
      std::cout << "deep_const_ptr::operator->() const" << std::endl;
      return pointerT::operator->();
    }
};
```

---

**Edit**
So I ended up, as suggested by [Luc Danton in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999442/588243), passing `std::unique_ptr<myClass::Private>` or `std::shared_ptr<myClass::Private>` to my custom `deep_const_ptr`:

```cpp
template<typename pointerTypeT>
class deep_const_ptr : public pointerTypeT {
  explicit deep_const_ptr(typename pointerTypeT::element_type* ptr) : pointerTypeT(ptr);
  typename pointerTypeT::element_type* operator->();
  const typename pointerTypeT::element_type* operator->() const;
};

deep_const_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Test::Private>> d_unique;
deep_const_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Test::Private>> d_shared;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your fast answers. As they are all pretty much the same, I accepted the one giving the actual line on how to instantiate `myClass`.

Comment: Does that really work when you try to use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @LucDanton, you'r right: `error: template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter`. I was to quick with ticking off this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against template template parameters in general. For instance `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are different in that the former accepts *two* type parameters and the latter just *one*. So if you declare e.g. `template<template<typename> class B, typename T> class foo;` then `foo<std::shared_ptr, int>` is valid but `foo<std::unique_ptr, int>` isn't.

In your particular case you could use `template<typename...> class B` as a parameter, because that kind of template template parameters is special. Still, this would only accept templates that only take type parameters (not even template template parameters). Sometimes this can be worked around with alias templates, sometimes it can't.

In my experience there are better alternatives -- for instance you can conditionally inherit:

```
template<typename T>
struct pointer: std::conditional</* Make a choice here*/, std::unique_ptr<T>, std::shared_ptr<T>>::type {};
```

Or why not just accept the smart pointer as the parameter itself:

```
template<typename Pointer>
struct foo {
    Pointer pointer;
    /* typename Pointer::element_type plays the role that T used to have */
};
```

---

The Standard Library itself takes some steps to avoid template template parameters: have you ever noticed that an `std::vector<T>` uses `std::allocator<T>` as an argument, and not `std::allocator`? As a tradeoff, it means that an Allocator must provide a `rebind` member alias template.

Comment: He can make a wrapper for `std::unique_ptr`: `template<typename T> class uniquePtr : public std::unique_ptr<T> {};`. It is even possible to create a 'meta-class' that will automatically wrap a template.

Comment: @Synxis See 'sometimes this can be worked around with alias templates'.

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't paid attention to this line.

Comment: Thanks, @LucDanton. See my edit of my solution. Directly passing the specialized `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to my custom pointer class seems the best and most intuitive way. I wasn't aware of `::element_type`. Should read the docs more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [***template template parameter***](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_template_arguments.htm):

```
//       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
template<template<typename> class B, class T>
class myClass : public B<T> { /* T is used in here */ };
```

Then, use that like:

```
myClass<firstBase,int> myIntClassObject;
myClass<secondBase,bool> myBoolClassObject;
```

For `std::unique_ptr`, you can make a wrapper:

```
template<typename T>
class uniquePtr : public std::unique_ptr<T>
{
};
```

or

```
template<typename T>
using uniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

`B` should be a template template parameter:

```
template<template <class> class B, class T>
class myClass : public B<T> { /* T is used in here */ };
```

Now you can give either `firstBase` or `secondBase` as the first template argument because they are templates.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use a [*template-template parameter*](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878) to get it to work:

```
template <
    template <class> class B, class T>
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class myClass : public B<T> { / ... / };
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you need is **template template parameters:**

```
template<template<class> class B, class T>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class myClass : public B<T> { /* T is used in here */ };
```

Now the first template argument for the `myClass` class template *must be itself a class template* that accepts one template (type) parameter. So, putting everything together:

```
template<class T>
class firstBase {};

template<class T>
class secondBase {};

template<template<class> class B, class T>
class myClass : public B<T> { /* T is used in here */ };
```

And here is how you would instantiate your `myclass` template to create a class that derives from `firstBase<int>`:

```
myClass<firstBase, int> obj;
```

Finally, here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24331).